# How to setup SharpLink and LavaLink correctly

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am using [Sharplink](https://github.com/Devoxin/SharpLink) and [LavaLink](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink) and have trouble getting the `LavalinkManager` setup and play music from my discord bot.

```
this._client = new DiscordSocketClient(
    new DiscordSocketConfig {LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose});
_lavalinkManager = new LavalinkManager(_client);
_lavalinkManager.Log += LavalinkManager_Log;
```

On DiscordClient#Ready event I do `await _lavalinkManager.StartAsync();` and the error logs posted below arise of them.

```
** 19:16:19 Lavalink    Connecting to Lavalink node at ws://0.0.0.0/
** 19:16:19 Lavalink    Failed to connect to Lavalink node at ws://0.0.0.0/
** 19:16:19 Lavalink    Waiting 6 seconds before reconnecting
```

And the `LavalinkManager_Log` method,

```
private Task LavalinkManager_Log(LogMessage arg1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"** {arg1}");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I've setup lavalink (Release date 25 August) and without providing a `application.yml` file hoping it to pickup default settings and am using SharpLink latest nuget as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at [this commit](https://github.com/Devoxin/SharpLink/commit/adf50dee08adfb40ac2b7b9c4dfa2a0b0f1f154d) they fixed this issue although it isn't yet updated on Nuget so you will have to specify the config and not use the default config. Another option is that you build the sharplink project and get the `dll` and add its reference in your project. This way you will have the latest features without relying on the Nuget update.

As of now you must add a config yourself in the code which corresponds to the `application.yml` there. Also verify that lavalink is actually running. Try to find out `listening on port xxxx` in the logs. You can add the config like this:

```
LavalinkManager lavalinkManager = new LavalinkManager(client, new LavalinkManagerConfig
{
    RESTHost = "localhost",
    RESTPort = 2333,
    WebSocketHost = "localhost",
    WebSocketPort = 2333,
    Authorization = "YOUR_SECRET_AUTHORIZATION_KEY",
    TotalShards = 1 
});
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The defaults of the application.yml as seen [here](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink/blob/master/LavalinkServer/application.yml.example) are to use 0.0.0.0 for the WS server.

In your case it cannot connect to that server cause it is either not running or on other IP address. I can't tell you this from the code provided and this will be something you have to discover for yourself.

Hope this helps